# Split to make Multiple calls

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, .net-core

Doing a proxy call to a microservice as follows

```
var empdetails = (await _proxy.Loaddetails(new EmpInfo { EmpId = empRequestsDict.Keys})).ToList();
```

`EmpId` is `IEnumerable<Long>`

The problem is I have more than 7000 rows in empRequestDict due to this it's taking more than 15seconds to retrieve the data. Is there any better way like splitting the empRequestDict into chunks so that parallel calls can be made at the same instance to reduce the response time?

Any other way of optimisation is also welcomed.

Comment: Is your database indexed correctly? Have you profiled to determine where the delay exists?

Comment: Do you own this proxy or at least have access to good documentation for it? You can of course batch it or even do it in parallel but are there other concerns like rate/compute limiting in place?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It feels like you're trying to fix the problem at the wrong end. The caller isn't taking long to make the call. The receiver is taking too long to process it. If you have control over receiver method, it would be worth looking into why it takes so long to process. You might also want to evaluate whether you need data for 7000 employee "keys" at once (i.e. whether "lazy loading" is possible.)

Answer (score 0):

You can chunk the requests as you describe, and then put the results back together into a single list:

```
var chunks = empRequestsDict.Keys.Chunk(1000);
var empDetailGroupTasks = chunks.Select(async empIds =>
    await _proxy.Loaddetails(new EmpInfo { EmpId = empids }));
var empDetailResults = await Task.WhenAll(empDetailGroupTasks);
var empdetails = empDetailResults.SelectMany(results => results).ToList();
```

However, it's hard to know whether 70 requests for 1000 items will go faster than 1 request for 7000 items. You'll have to do your own testing.